# How can I add a running total of one column to an Access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a query that contains in one field the percentage of total sales corresponding to a specific product in the past 12 months. For example:

Product 1 - 38%
Product 2 - 25%
Product 3 - 16%
(...)

The records are sorted in descending order by the percentage column, and the sum of that has to be 100%. I want to create a new column that adds the previous percentages as a running total, like this:

Product 1 - 38% - 38%
Product 2 - 25% - 63%
Product 3 - 16% - 79%
(... until it reaches the last product and a 100% sub-total)

How could I do this?

Comment: Do the products have an ID field? Are they actually named `Product1, Product2`..?

Comment: No, they have different names. It was just an example.

Comment: Is there an ID field we can use?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `ID` field, or a date field, you can use a variation of this correlated subquery.

```
SELECT t.*,
     t.productpct+[prev_value] AS RunningSum,

 (select sum([ProductPct])            
 from test AS t2                   
  WHERE             
  t2.ID < t.ID  
 ) AS Prev_Value

FROM test AS t;
```

There are people who are way better at SQL than I, however if this helps or gives you your answer then great.

Comment: Thanks for that. Now that you say it, I think I could use the amount of sales as an ID since it will be in descendent order. Anyways, could I use the percentage o each one as the ID field since it's in descendent order? And what does t, test and T2 mean? Thank you.

Comment: test is the name of your table. t and t2 are table aliases. So your table name would replace `test`, everything else could stay the same. The percentage could accurately identify each row, possibly, however it isn't always guaranteed that the percentage will be different, is it?

Comment: And what happens if the data is not on a table but in a query? Also prev_value and ProductPct should stay the same?

Comment: prev_value can stay the same, and ProductPct is the field name for the percentages. You'll have to play around with it. It could work. I don't know, I can't see the query.