# Running totals in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have an excel spreadsheet that I want in Access. The spreadsheet is a petty cash tracking sheet.

Basically, I have a date column, 3 "type" fields (Appointment 1, Appointment 2, Appointment 3), a "Cash in" column.

Appointment 1  $25
  Appointment 2  $50
  Appointment 3  $100
  Cash In, Manually inputted (today, we deposited $300)

"Cash out" is automatically calculated by summing Appointments 1-3.

"Remaining balance" references the previous remaining balance then subtracts Cash Out from it and adds Cash In to it from that date.

How can I implement this in Access?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add a running total of one column to an Access query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24314159/how-can-i-add-a-running-total-of-one-column-to-an-access-query)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Access 2010 or higher, you can use the new calculated fields, otherwise, cann't do it directly on the table so must do it programmatically on a form.